# The source map 'data:application/json;base64,';' for file 'domain/systemjs/dist/system.src.js' could not be loaded correctly due to an error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I have problem with Visual studio.

I'm developing angular 2 / Web Api (.net 4.6.1) application. 
When application is starting, that visual studio freeze for ~30s and to Output console write

> The source map 'data:application/json;base64,';' for file
>   'domain/systemjs/dist/system.src.js' could not be loaded correctly due
>   to an error.

Do you have experience with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mino, did you found a solution for that issue?

Comment: Hi. unfortunately I didn't found solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error message when investigating on ***why there are no symbols loaded for my breakpoints, set in TypeScript files***

**Problem**

I used *Webpack Task Runner*, started in watch-mode to create the bundles.
WebpackTaskRunner started webpack with param "-d" - that caused the issue.

**Solution (for me)**

- Remove "*WebPack Task Runner*" Extension from VS
- Add "*NPM Task Runner*" - Extension to VS
- Add the following npm-script to package:

  "webpack-watch": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack --color --watch"
- Finally created a binding in Task Runner Explorer for "Project Open" and the "webpack-watch" script.

Using that binding, webpack is started in watch-mode (without "-d" param) after opening the project in VS.
This solved my issues (no more error messages) and the breakpoints in Typescript-Files were hit.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunately I don't have WebPack extension installed :-(